# Electric potential at midpoint?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

[image]

I understand that if you assume the field is uniform between R and S then you can use E=V/d to get E=(30-20)/(0.5)=20Vm^(-1), so the answer is C (which is correct according to the mark scheme).

But how do we know the field is unform between R and S in the first place? Or is there another way of solving this that doesn't assume anything about uniformity?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the potential lines for a moment. You will find that for equal change in distance, there is equal change in potential. Means, if I move 0.5 m to the left, the potential increase is 10 V.

In other words, we have equidistant equipotential lines which is a graphical way of denoting uniform field. Whenever you see straight equipotential lines, it means that direction is constant. If the spacing is also same, it means strength is constant. If both are constant, it means field is uniform and hence the answer.